# @InjectMocks @Autowired together issue

Tags: java, spring, annotations, mockito, autowired

could you help me please,
some code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestUnit2 {

    @Mock
    private MongoOperations mongoTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private WorkcircleRepositoryMongoImpl workCircleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WorkcircleServiceImpl workCircleServiceImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    ....
    when(mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(), Person.class)).thenReturn(expectedPerson);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    ... workCircleServiceImpl.find()...

    }
```

But  test is failed:
NP in "... workCircleServiceImpl.find()..." line,

in separate way @InjectMocks & @Autowired  work, but together are not worked.

Comment: I think that you should use only one of `@InjectMocks` and `@Autowired` ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually when you are unit testing, you shouldn't initialize Spring context. 
So remove Autowiring.

Usually when you do integration testing, you should use real dependencies.
So remove mocking.

You are mixing integration and unit test here.